# Java installation for Solaris Studio 12.2

Tags: 10.04, 64-bit, java

I have Solaris Studio almost working. My only issue seems to be Java.

Here is what I get:

============================

```
aflory@aflory-laptop:~$ solstudio &
[1] 1723
aflory@aflory-laptop:~$ Solaris Studio is unable to find a supported version of Java.
Solaris Studio supports Java version 1.6.0_13 and newer and looks for a valid Java installation in the following order:
1) Location specified with --jdkhome command line option
2) In PATH environment variable
3) At /usr/jdk/latest location, if exists
4) At /usr/java location, if exists
5) At /usr location, if exists
```

============================

I try typing `--jdkhome` in the console but I get an command not found error.

I have added the following to my `/home/aflory/.bashrc` file:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_24/bin:/home/aflory/solstudio12.2/bin
export PATH
```

I am running Ubuntu 10.04 64bit.

I tried installing the 64 bit version of Java JDK, then I tried installing the 32bit version of Java JDK.

I don't believe there is a 64bit version of Solaris Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message (and the [manpage](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19205-01/821-2676/solstudio.1.html)) suggests running the command with the "--jdkhome" option, passing in the JDK installation directory as the argument; e.g.,

```
$ solstudio --jdkhome /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_24/
```

You might also try setting JAVA_HOME, a commonly used env var to designate your preferred Java installation directory, used by various tools. (It's a convention, not a requirement.)  This simplifies upgrades of your JRE/JDK.

(Even better, set a symlink from /usr/java/latest to /usr/java/{your_jdk}, and set JAVA_HOME to /usr/java/latest... but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader. If you have the "alternatives" (or galternatives) package available & installed, just use that....)

For example:

Set it...

```
prompt>  export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_24
```

Test it...

```
prompt> $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version
```

Use it...

```
prompt> solstudio --jdkhome $JAVA_HOME
```